# Expected number of trials until $k$ failures or number of trials reach $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

I am trying to find the expected number of trails until the $k$-th failure
or until the number of trials hit $n$, whichever comes first. The success   probability of the trial is $p$.

My calculation gave me the below result.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i{{n}\choose{i}} p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i} + \sum_{i=k}^n i { k-1+i \choose i} p^{i}(1-p)^k
$$

But it seems the result is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i{{n}\choose{i}} p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i} + \sum_{i=k}^n i { i-1 \choose k-1} p^{i-k}(1-p)^k
$$

I don't know what is wrong with my result and how I can get the correct result.

Comment: What happens if you never fail (which occurs with probability $p^n$)? Are we working conditional on the assumption that you actually fail at least $k$ times in the $n$ trials?

Comment: @jlammy. Yes, I am interested in the case  until the $k$-th failure or until $n$ is reached.

Comment: So just to be crystal clear: we want the expected number of trials until either we have $k$ failures or we hit $n$ trials, whichever comes first?

Comment: @jlammy yes you are correct. I edited the question to be precise.

Comment: What if the $k$-th failure occurs at the $n$-th trial? Which event happened first, the k-th failure or the number of trials hitting $n$?

Comment: What do you mean by "but it seems"?

Comment: @Jamāl, number of trials hitting $n$.

Comment: @user, it is the given answer (just answer. no explanations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both expressions are wrong. The correct one is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \color {red}n{{n}\choose{i}} p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i} + \sum_{i=k}^n i { i-1 \choose k-1} p^{i-k}(1-p)^k.\tag1
$$
Here the first term accounts for the events with the number of failures ($i $) in $n $ trials being less than $k $, and the second term accounts for the events with $k $ failures (the $k $-th failure being achieved in $i $-th trial).

The equation (1) can be written also in a more symmetric form:
$$
n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{{n}\choose{i}} p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i} + k\sum_{i=k}^n { i\choose k} p^{i-k}(1-p)^k.\tag2
$$

Comment: can you please explain the result ?  I didn't get why you have $n$ as the multiplicative factor in the first term. Also, how you got second term ?

Comment: The number of trials with "under-failures" is $n $, is not it? It is impossible to explain why the factor could be $i $. The expected value is $\sum$ value$\times $ probability  (value).

Comment: Fantastic answer. Please can the question asker put this as top answer instead of the other as it is incorrect.

Comment: @oskarszarowicz Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ denote the number of trials until the $k$-th failure. The distribution of $T$ is given by
$$
\mathsf{P}(T=i)=\binom{i-1}{k-1}(1-p)^kp^{i-k},\quad i\ge k.
$$
Then (assuming that $n\ge k$) the expectation of $T\wedge n$ is
$$
\mathsf{E}[T\wedge n]=\sum_{i=k}^\infty (i\wedge n)\cdot \mathsf{P}(T=i)=\sum_{i=k}^n i\cdot \mathsf{P}(T=i)+n\cdot \mathsf{P}(T>n),
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{P}(T>n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{i}(1-p)^ip^{n-i},
$$
i.e., it is the probability that the number of failures in the first $n$ trials is less than $k$. Alternatively,
$$
\mathsf{P}(T>n)=1-\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom{i-1}{k-1}(1-p)^kp^{i-k},
$$

Comment: I saw the notatin $i  \wedge  j$ in many places. What does it translate into in probability ? In plain language I read it as a joint event. What does $T \wedge n$ means ?

Comment: $a\wedge b \equiv\min\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Here you assumed that the trials continue even after $k$-th failure or hitting $n$-th trial? I interpreted the "until" as a stopping criteria. That would change the sample space right? But the expected number of trials remain the same i guess.

Comment: @Jamāl Can you be more specific? The stopping criteria is the $k$-th failure or the number of trials hits $n$.

Comment: You have considered the cases when $T>n$ also right? So the trials continued even after number of trials hit $n$.